# Add to an array and then adjust order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Say I have the following array.

```
$a = ("a","c","d","e","f");
```

How can I add the value b, after a and keep the rest of the array so that the result is.

```
$a = ("a","b","c","d","e","f");
```

Comment: [Array Splice](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-splice.php) `array_splice($a, 1, 0, 'b');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is quite simple you can use  `array_splice`

```
$a = array("a", "c", "d", "e", "f");
   array_splice($a, 1, 0, "b");
```

Comment: This is a php question not javascript

Comment: my mistake now added the correct solution for php

Comment: This is an insert only, it replace b with c, the result for me is ("a",b","d","e","f")

Comment: use this code it's working fine `$a = array("a", "c", "d", "e", "f");
   array_splice($a, 1, 0, "b");
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($a);` `Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
)`